Return LAST CELL POSITION based on TWO criteria
I'm having trouble returning the LAST CELL POSITION based on two criterias:

cell = "R"
wherever position #1 (above) is found, if this position +3 columns = F2

I found a formula that helped me to do this for returning last cell position for the first criteria:
=max(arrayformula(if(DATA!T5:5="R", COLUMN($3:$3), 0)))

*the above formula works.
But I'd like to add criteria #2.  What I'm hoping for is something like:
=max(arrayformula(if(AND(DATA!T5:5="R", OFFSET(DATA!T5:5,,3)=$F$2), COLUMN($3:$3), 0)))

*this above formula doesn't work- returns 0 when it shouldn't.
attached is the file, with cell in question highlighted in turquois.
text
tried offset function but returns incorrect value

try:
=MAX(INDEX(IF(IFERROR((DATA!T5:5="R")*(OFFSET(DATA!T5:5,,3)=$F$2)), COLUMN($3:$3), 0)))


or try without IF:
=MAX(INDEX(IFERROR((DATA!T5:5="R")*(OFFSET(DATA!T5:5,,3)=$F$2)*COLUMN($3:$3))), 0)


this works great!  thanks again @player0.  i did not know you can multiply criterias.
